# Eclipse: All the files of the project became empty

Tags: java, eclipse, recovery

While working on a project using eclipse-java-juno, my project was running fine and I was able to run properly. Next day when I opened eclipse, all the contents of all the files are lost. Files on disk are empty. 
I can show screenshot of the project explorer while all files are having 0 kb size.

- What could have caused this?
- Any option for recovery?

p.s. To mail my code, I copied it from eclipse project explorer to desktop and made a ZIP file. Files in that zip folder are also empty.

Answer (score 2):

It simply looks like you have lost the data on your file system (Hard disk) assuming you are using windows ,It does not look like an eclipse problem to me.

If you know where your workspace location is and where the actual files were on hard-disk which you were pointing to from eclipse, then just go to that location and confirm if they exist.

If they exists on hard-disk Hurray!!..Simply re-create project in eclipse by pointing to files at this location in project/workspace.

If they don't exists on hard-disk, then they are deleted,See if you can find in "recycle bin" else If you have any recovery tool. Else use "repository" (like SVN) next time , this would be a classic example to someone to tell importance of using Repository for code and constant backup's.